# Transfer the Value of a link when clicking on said link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I created a simple list with [md-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table):

```
<tr md-row md-select="device" md-on-select="logItem" md-auto-select="options.autoSelect" ng-repeat="device in devices.data">
<td md-cell style='text-align:left;vertical-align:middle'>{{device.ID}}</td>
</tr>
```

My goal is code where I can click on one of the lists entry and it opens another site/state/view whose controller can work with value, e.g. the device.ID and can dynamically create a view with data for this device.ID.

I guess you could do it with a php post/get but sadly that's not possible due to project requirements.

Comment: And what is your question exactly? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a `ng-click` that invokes a function that writes the device.ID into a $rootScope variable:

```
<td md-cell><a href="" ng-click="gotoDevices(device.ID)">{{device.ID}}</a></td>
```

In your controller the `gotoDevices function` could look like this:

```
$scope.gotoDevices = function(deviceID){
  $state.go('i_liveDevice');
  $rootScope.liveDevice=deviceID 
};
```

make sure you inject the `$rootScope` and `$state` dependencies into your controller